# Rails4: Cannot pass value between methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot pass value between methods. In my OrderController, I want to pass the `@order_id` from **create** method to **order_show** method. When I check  `@order_id` inside `order_show`, its value become nil!

Not sure how to fix it.

Order controller

```
def create_order
  @neworder = Order.new(order_params)
  if @neworder.save
    @order_id=@neworder.orderid
    #raise @order_id.inspect <---------shows orderid
    redirect_to order_show_path
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

def order_show
  raise @order_id.inspect <--------orderid is nil!
  @orderdlt=Order.find(@order_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `create_order` method to redirect request to  order_show_path by passing the order's id. So you can access order id from url as parameter.

So it should be something like this;

```
def create_order
   @neworder = Order.new(order_params)
   if @neworder.save
      @order_id=@neworder.orderid
      #raise @order_id.inspect <---------shows orderid
      redirect_to order_show_path(@order_id)
   else
      render "new"
   end
end

def order_show
   @order_id = params[:id]
   raise @order_id.inspect <--------orderid is nil!
   @orderdlt=Order.find(@order_id)
end
```

You need to setup your routes too.

Comment: Thanks. It works. However, get request expose the order id. I want to hide the orderid. redirect_to does not support post request. I fixed the problem by using session, but looking for a better way.

Comment: If you want to hide order id from url you need to store it in a session variable as you said. Something like; `session[:order_id] = @orderid`